# ant Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: ant

This is driving me nuts.
When running any ant command (even `ant -version`), I always get the following error on Mac OSX:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

I removed and re-installed ant entirely, and still get the same error.

[image]

For our company we have to run Java7 to run the command, so I created an alias.

This used to work, I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: Did you change the jre in the build configuration window? If i'm not wrong 52 is java 7

Comment: @tomyforever Actually 52 is java8. I switch to Java7 runtime with the alias, which is 51.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I see you have java 1.7 installed and post that you have installed Ant 1.10.

Ant 1.10 requires jdk 8
Refer : http://ant.apache.org/

> The Apache Ant team currently maintains two lines of development. The
>   1.9.x releases require Java5 at runtime and **1.10.x requires Java8 at runtime**. Both lines are based off of Ant 1.9.7 and the 1.9.x releases
>   are mostly bug fix releases while additional new features are
>   developed for 1.10.x. **We recommend using 1.10.x unless you are
>   required to use versions of Java prior to Java8 during the build
>   process.**

Try using Ant 1.9.x if you can't use java 8

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of minimum java version for given ant version
[image]