# Ant sonar command not works

Tags: ant, sonarqube

I am trying to insert sonarqube setup on build.xml, getting unsupported error.
My build Java version support 1.6
Ant.sonar.qube support 2.5

If I use have version 1.8 my ant sonar command is working.ant command is not working.if I use java 1.6 ant is working and ant sonar is not working.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you modified and which exact error message you see?

Comment: I am trying to insert sonar properties in existing build.xml file.getting an error unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: How do you "insert" these properties? Which **exact** (word by word) error message do you see?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49303389/ant-unsupported-major-minor-version-52-0 help?

Comment: I tried these all but still getting same error.

Comment: You've been asked twice to provide the error message. Ignoring people doesn't really encourage anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You already know exactly what your problem is:

> If I use have version 1.8 my ant sonar command is working

...

> if I use java 1.6 ant is working and ant sonar is not working.

You're facing incompatibility with the version of Java you're trying to use. Since analysis *will not* work with 1.6, you're best off upgrading to Java 8 and working to make whatever your other Ant target is work with that.